# "renvoyer à ses affaires" ?

Tags: sens

In the news, talking about Sarkozy, I heard:

> Et bien d’abord pour Nicolas Sarkozy, C’est un coup dur, sa troisième mise en examen. L’ancien président **est renvoyé à ses affaires,** lui qui se glissait depuis quelques temps dans la peau du vieux sage à droite.

What does that bolded portion mean?

Answer (score 4):

*Affaires* means (court) cases here.

Sarkozy is "sent back" / "returned" to his various cases, i.e. he is kind of expelled from the "old wise man" position he was slightly reaching to a much more unconfortable one where he has to defend himself against various charges.

Here are similar French idioms, often used figuratively :

> - *renvoyé à ses (chères) études* : dismissed, sent back to school
> - *renvoyé dans ses foyers* : demobilized, sent back home
> - *renvoyé dans ses cordes* : sent on the ropes (like in a boxing ring)
> - *renvoyé dans ses buts* : sent back to his goal line/posts (soccer), sent packing
> - *renvoyé à ses démons* : sent back to his personal demons